# How to open hidden .bash_profile file on Mac?

Tags: flutter, command-line, terminal

Trying to add flutter to my cmd line in the terminal. I can't access the hidden .bash_profile file. I can see it using cmd/shift/. but I can't open it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably duplicate of some question, but anyway here it is:
With this you can add flutter to your path, please change the path to your installation folder.

```
 export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```

If you still want to open `.bash_profile`, you can do it with some text editor you have installed:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
open ~/.bash_profile
nano ~/.bash_profile
mate ~/.bash_profile
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: I changed the path and it seems to go through just fine. I check with the echo command. Then if I use which flutter on the next line or anything else it says flutter not found. The touch ~/.bash_profile command, also says command not found: flutter. Even if I type the command clear it says zsh: command not found: clear. I'm following this tutorial https://youtu.be/x0uinJvhNxI at the 23 min mark. My terminal just doesn't seem to work. I apologize if this has been discussed before I wasn't able to find anything that works.

Comment: Hi @Ziyah, maybe your terminal is then using Z Shell (zsh) and you should look for `~/.zshrc` instead of `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I don't have that file I can see the .bash_profile file it's just grey and won't open. At the top of my terminal it doe say zsh though.

Comment: You have to create `~/.zshrc` file then, just run e.g. `nano ~/.zshrc`